# Intersection form on manifolds with boundary

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, low-dimensional-topology

It is a "basic fact" that the intersection form of a closed oriented 4k-dimensional manifold is unimodular. (Could anyone point me to a reference to a proof of this fact?)

What can be said about the determinant of the intersection form of an oriented 4k-manifold with boundary? What invariant(s) of the boundary can be read off from the determinant?

Thanks!

Comment: There is no reference -- it's an immediate corollary of Poincare Duality. For boundary, use Poincare-Lefschetz duality.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure that this is not relevant anymore but still. I just expand a bit the comment given above.

It is not hard to prove. It is evident that intersection form could be viewed as form of pairing homology and cohomology in dimension $2k.$ Thus one needs to prove that in suitable basis in homology and cohomology intersection form has identity matrix. But this result follows from the fact that we can take dual elements of basis in cohomology and thus obtain an identity matrix. $AQB=I,$ where $Q$ is a matrix of intersection form in some basis and $A$ and $B$ are respective transition matrices in homology and cohomology. Since both $A$ and $B$ are unimodular $Q$ is unimodular as well.